# Print the positive, negative, and all entries made using while loop

Tags: c

So I've tried to calculate the average of the positive and negative entries made in the while loop but I can't seem to enter any type of number into the console. So I need to enter numbers as long as it's not zero and add the positive numbers as well as negative numbers. I'm required to count how many positive and negative entries were entered. I need also to print the average of the positive and negatives entries.

Here is my code:

```
int num; 
int positivenum = 0, negativenum = 0;
int cpositive = 0, cnegative = 0;
float average = 0;
printf("Enter a positive and negative integer:");
while (num!=0)
{
scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num > 0){
    positivenum += num;
    cpositive++;
    }
    
    else if (num < 0){
    negativenum += num;
    cnegative++;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In particular, is `num` initialised properly?

Comment: As suspected, `num` is not initialised. so `while (num!=0)` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Do I need to initialize num to zero?

Comment: You need to init the variable. Local non-static variables in C are not initialised automatically. But not to 0 as the loop will not be entered. Alternatively change the loop to be a `do/while`.

Comment: just initialize `num = 1` before starting of while loop.

Comment: If you initialize 'num' to zero, then 'while (num!=0) is always zero and the optimizer will remove all your loop:(

Comment: do{scanf......} while() ?  or just while(true){scanf...} with some break check in the loop?

Comment: I will try these methods since I'm still a beginner, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Okay, so what is your *question*? Did something wrong happen when you tried the code? What happened, and how is that different from what you want to happen?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly when `do while` is judicious:

```c
int num; 
int positivenum = 0, negativenum = 0;
int cpositive = 0, cnegative = 0;
printf("Enter a positive and negative integer:");
do
{
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num > 0){
        positivenum += num;
        cpositive++;
    }
    
    else if (num < 0){
        negativenum += num;
        cnegative++;
    }
} while (num!=0);

if (cpositive > 0)
    printf("Average of positive numbers: %f\n", (double)positivenum / (double)cpositive);

if (cnegative > 0)
    printf("Average of negative numbers: %f\n", (double)negativenum / (double)cnegative);
```

Comment: Glad it helped! if it solved your problem you may select it as answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Changed the type of your counts from int to unsigned (negative counts doesn't make sense).  Also moved the prompt inside the loop and and wrote a function to calculate the average:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void average(const char *what, int value, unsigned count) {
    if(!count) return;
    printf("average of %s numbers: %f\n", what, (float) value / count);
}

int main() {
    int num;
    int positivenum = 0, negativenum = 0;
    unsigned cpositive = 0, cnegative = 0;
    for(;;) {
        printf("Enter a positive and negative integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if(!num) break;
        if(num < 0) {
            negativenum += num;
            cnegative++;
            continue;
        }
        positivenum += num;
        cpositive++;
    }

    average("positive", positivenum, cpositive);
    average("negative", negativenum, cnegative);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num; 
int positivenum = 0, negativenum = 0;
int cpositive = 0, cnegative = 0;
int range = 0;
int i = 0;
printf("Enter the range.\n");
scanf("%d", &range);
printf("Enter a positive and negative integer:\n");
do
{
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num > 0){
        positivenum += num;
        cpositive++;
    }
    
    else if (num < 0){
        negativenum += num;
        cnegative++;
    }
    i++;
} while ( (num!=0) && (i < range));

if (cpositive > 0)
    printf("Average of positive numbers: %f\n", (float)positivenum / (float)cpositive);

if (cnegative > 0)
    printf("Average of negative numbers: %f\n", (float)negativenum / (float)cnegative);

}
```

I have also added a range to break the loop.

Comment: well what exactly does "range" do since you added it to the code?